# SSIS Lookup transformation lookup key not working properly

Tags: ssis

I have a lookup transformation that lookups up field ContainerSrcID_Barcode DT_WSTR(20) field from table A against ContainerSrcID DT_WSTR(40) from table B and values are being kicked out to an error table if they do not match.  I've noticed that values that exists in both of those key field are being kicked out to error table.  The only difference I see in those two key is the length size.  Is there another reason why values that are in both of those keys are considered not matched?

Comment: For example, value 7055200201 is in ContainerSrcID_Barcode in table A does exists in field ContainerSrcID in table B, but value is kicked to an error table because the lookup transformation did not match.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the fields doesn't matter.  If the lookup is not finding matches, then the data doesn't actually match.   Probably you have whitespace characters or special non-ascii characters (like carriage returns, etc) in one of the fields and not the other.

Comment: Is there a way I can identify if the field has trailing whitespaces are tossing off the match or special non-ascii characters?

Comment: I would suggest doing a TRIM() of both columns you are comparing in the lookup.